# When is a vector in the image of a bilinear map?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

In this case I have a bilinear map defined as:
$\varphi:V\times V\rightarrow U$ with:

> $$\varphi(x,y)=x_1y_1c_1+x_1y_2c_2+x_2y_1c_3+x_2y_2c_4$$

Here $\{c_1,\ldots,c_4\}$ is a basis of $U$ and $V$ has dimension 2 with basis $\{b_1,b_2\}$ (so you can think of $x:=x_1b_1+x_2b_2$ and "" for $y$)

Given a vector, $z\in U$ I want to know under what conditions $z=\sum^4_{i=1}z_ic_i\in S$ where:
$S:=\{\varphi(x,y)\in U\ |\ x\in V\wedge y\in V\}$ (the image of the bilinear map)

### I am looking for solving this in the general case

So please no specific-to-this-question tricks. If this question were different I'd like to have learned how to solve it (rather than learning a trick for this exact question). It annoys me I can't seem to "solve" the equations:
$$\begin{array}{ll}z_1=x_1y_1 &z_2=x_1y_2\\ z_3=x_2y_1 & z_4=x_2y_2\end{array}$$
into some level set $\{z\in Z|f(z_1,\ldots,z_4)=c\}$ form.

### Suspected answer

I believe that $z\in S\iff z_1z_4-z_2z_3=0$ but "I pulled this out of a hat" if you will by thinking "it looks a bit like matrx multipication" and taking a guess.

### Context

I am trying to find a bilinear map whose image is **not** a vector subspace of $U$. This means that finding a basis of the image will not work (and indeed has not worked for me)

Comment: You can prove one direction of your guessed $\iff$ statement, right?

Comment: Yeah @LeeMosher I'm not asking how to prove the statement I'm asking how to find the condition (because my $z_1z_4-z_2z_3=0$ is a "lucky/educated guess") but yes the $z_1z_4-z_2z_3\implies z\in S$ is easy to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice for this particular case you can divide to cancel out variables and see that
$$\frac{z_{1}}{z_{2}} = \frac{z_{3}}{z_{4}} = \frac{y_{1}}{y_{2}}$$
and
$$\frac{z_{1}}{z_{3}} = \frac{z_{2}}{z_{4}} = \frac{x_{1}}{x_{2}}.$$
Each of these gives that $z_{1}z_{4}-z_{2}z_{3} = 0$.
You have essentially two cases: if $z_1=z_2=0$,
then take $x_1=0$, $x_{2}=1$, $y_{1}=z_{3}$, and $y_{2} = z_{4}$.
If $z_{1}=z_{4}=0$, then we either have that $x_{1}=y_{2}=0$ and so $z_{2}=0$, in which case take $x_{2}=1$ and $y_{1}=z_{3}$,
or else $y_{1}=x_{2}=0$, in which case $z_{3}=0$, and you can similarly find a solution.

In general, you will get a whole bunch of quadratic equations involving two variables, and the image will be the intersection of all the solution sets. This is explained in the link posted by WimC involving Segre varieties.

Comment: So one of the reasons I was scared to involve divisions (with things like $z_1-z_2=x_1(b_1-b_2)$ is because what if certain things are zero. Hold please, I can only get as far as $z_1z_4=z_3z_2=\frac{y_1}{y_2}z_2z_4$ without paper and I can't quite see the end. __+1 in good faith__

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'm not being bad-lazy BTW, I'd call it "good lazy" because I'm looking for a polynomial time solution rather than the NP 24 case analysis. Suppose my $U$ had been 6 dimensional, it'd be 720 case analysis then! Lastly, thanks for that $x_2=1$ on the first line to your last comment, I just remembered that I'm not trying to parameterise the pre-image, $\varphi^{-1}(z)$ but simply show $\exists x,y$. Take care.

Answer (score 2):

This question is equivalent to asking what $2\times 2$ matrices have rank $1$. (Consider the matrix product $x\,y^{\textrm{t}}$ for two column vectors $x$ and $y$.)  In other words, what $2\times 2$ matrices are non-zero and have pairwise dependent columns (or rows)? This characterization also works well in higher dimensions. See [segre embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segre_embedding) for pointers.

Comment: So that mapping takes (quote) "$\sigma:P^m\times P^n\rightarrow P^{(n+1)(m+1)-1}$" my $m,n=2$ (so the image is 5 dimensional rather than 4) - also there must be a simpler construction, this question feels like late-first/early-second year linear algebra. Thanks for telling me about the Segre Embedding though!

Comment: @AlecTeal Rank one matrices do not form a linear space. Consider matrices that are zero everywhere except for a single diagonal entry.

Comment: I would still love to know how to apply it to this question....

Comment: @AlecTeal If "it" is the Segre embedding: it is the projectification of $(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2) \mapsto (x_1y_1, x_1y_2, x_2y_1, x_2y_2)$ so a map from $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ to $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: But how can that be applied to this question? I really don't get your answer.

Comment: @AlecTeal My answer is self contained. The reference to Segre was just FYI. In particular $$\begin{pmatrix} z_1 & z_2 \\ z_3 & z_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \end{pmatrix}$$ if and only if the left hand matrix is singular (this follows from the right hand product).